# PHP / SQL page never stops loading during MYSQL connection

Tags: php, html, mysql

I´m new to SQL and PHP, so pardon me for asking something that´s probably very simple, but for some reason, even though I don´t have any loops in my code, when it get´s to this part, it continues loading the page indefinitely. Here is the snippet of the code that does that.

```
mysql_connect("localhost:8080", "root@localhost") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("tickets");

$val1 = $_POST["Name"];
$val2 = $_POST["Mail"];
$val3 = $_POST["Betreff"];
$val4 = $_POST["Wichtigkeitsstufe"];
$val5 = $_POST["Nachricht"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Ticket (Name, E-MailOderErreichbarkeitBeiRückfragen, RaumbezeichnungBzwNummer, Wichtigkeitsstufe, Problembeschreibungausführlich)
        VALUES ({$val1}, {$val2}, {$val3}, {$val4}, {$val5})";
```

I get the values for $val1,2,3,... from input boxes in an html file.
Thanks in advance, cheers!

Edit:
I was running both the DB and the webserver on the same ports. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Is your database really at port 8080? Try using simply `localhost`, or `localhost:3306` (default Mysql port)

Comment: @Damien Pirsy it´s on port 4433 and 8080, I changed the ports because 80 and 433 were apparently busy and I didn´t know by what. Supposedly Skype likes those ports, but I don´t have Skype installed on this PC. going on localhost::3306 gives me: X���
5.5.5-10.1.9-MariaDB�
��^WxxpKe<�ÿ÷�? ����������9JJpy.v*iTIP�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order

Comment: So the DB is on 4433?

Comment: I can understand your webserver being on ports 4433 and 8080; but MySQL?!? Why not simply use the standard port 3306 for MySQL?

Comment: @Mark Baker is that bad? Does putting both the webserver and the DB on the same ports overlap each other? It didn´t give me any errors when I ran them so I guessed that was the way I had to do it. Like I said, new to anything web-related. :(

Comment: Yes, using the same ports for both the webserver and for the database is bad, no wonder the poor servers are confused

Comment: Haha alright, thanks a bunch. Should be working now, cheers!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to attacks and functions are deprecated, don't ever use it in production. You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @rap-2-h it´s just for a tiny project for school, nothing more. I´ll look into it though, thanks!